# how to remove \n from my dataframe output?

Tags: pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL0GL.png%60)

My code are as below:
i am trying to learn data science and found this \n in my output.
can someone help to sort it out ?

Year\n  Team\n  GP\n    GS\n    MPG\n   FG%\n   3P%\n   FT%\n   RPG\n   APG\n   SPG\n   BPG\n   PPG\n

0   1984–85\n   Chicago\n   82  82  38.3    .515    .173    .845    6.5 5.9 2.4 .8  28.2\n

1   1985–86\n   Chicago\n   18  7   25.1    .457    .167    .840    3.6 2.9 2.1 1.2 22.7\n

2   1986–87\n   Chicago\n   82  82  40.0    .482    .182    .857    5.2 4.6 2.9 1.5 37.1*\n

3   1987–88\n   Chicago\n   82  82  40.4*   .535    .132    .841    5.5 5.9 3.2*    1.6 35.0*\n

4   1988–89\n   Chicago\n   81  81  40.2*   .538    .276    .850    8.0 8.0 2.9 .8  32.5*\n

5   1989–90\n   Chicago\n   82  82  39.0    .526    .376    .848    6.9 6.3 2.8*    .7  33.6*\n

6   1990–91†\n  Chicago\n   82  82  37.0    .539    .312    .851    6.0 5.5 2.7 1.0 31.5*\n

7   1991–92†\n  Chicago\n   80  80  38.8    .519    .270    .832    6.4 6.1 2.3 .9  30.1*\n

8   1992–93†\n  Chicago\n   78  78  39.3    .495    .352    .837    6.7 5.5 2.8*    .8  32.6*\n

9   1994–95\n   Chicago\n   17  17  39.3    .411    .500    .801    6.9 5.3 1.8 .8  26.9\n

10  1995–96†\n  Chicago\n   82  82  37.7    .495    .427    .834    6.6 4.3 2.2 .5  30.4*\n

11  1996–97†\n  Chicago\n   82  82  37.9    .486    .374    .833    5.9 4.3 1.7 .5  29.6*\n

12  1997–98†\n  Chicago\n   82  82  38.8    .465    .238    .784    5.8 3.5 1.7 .5  28.7*\n

13  2001–02\n   Washington\n    60  53  34.9    .416    .189    .790    5.7 5.2 1.4 .4  22.9\n

14  2002–03\n   Washington\n    82  67  37.0    .445    .291    .821    6.1 3.8 1.5 .5  20.0\n

15  Career\n    1,072   1,039   38.3    .497    .327    .835    6.2 5.3 2.3 .8  30.1\n  None

16  All-Star\n  13  13  29.4    .472    .273    .750    4.7 4.2 2.8 .5  20.2\n  None

```
response = requests.get(links)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table', class_ = 'wikitable sortable')
all_raws = table.find_all('tr')
data = []
for raw in all_raws:
    raw_list = raw.find_all('td')                
//raw_list will print only last raw of table 

[<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">All-Star </td>, <td>13</td>, <td>13</td>, <td>29.4</td>, <td>.472</td>, <td>.273</td>, <td>.750</td>, <td>4.7</td>, <td>4.2</td>, <td>2.8</td>, <td>.5</td>, <td>20.2</td>]

    dataRaw = []
    for cell in raw_list:
        dataRaw.append(cell.text)                # datRaw will print only last raw  ['All-Star\n', '13', '13', '29.4', '.472', '.273', '.750', '4.7', '4.2', '2.8', '.5', '20.2\n']

    data.append(dataRaw)

data = data[1:]


header_list = []
col_header = table.find_all('th')
for col in col_header:
    header_list.append(col.text)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = header_list
df
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
df['<column name>'] = df.<column name>.str.replace(r'\n', '')
```